# Jquery: $(document).click doenst work in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, document

I do have a problem regarding $(document).click.

There is a user bar on top of my page I am currently working on. On the upper right-hand side is a box with the username of the currently logged in user. Clicking on it opens a dialog with logout, my profile etc. Some links basically, just as Facebook does.

You can close this popup either by clicking on the box again or clicking on the document ($(document).click).

It works fine on Chrome but Firefox has some issues. Firefox is interpreting the box itself as "document" and closes immediately after I click on the box. That's stupid since I do have links on it and I am not able to click them because FF is closing the box on click.

Any idea how to find a workaround for that?

EDIT: Some code

$(document).ready(function() {

```
/*
***** user options popup *****
*/

$("#userputrigger").click(function() {
    if ($("#userpopup").length > 0)
    {
        $("#userpopup").remove();
        $(".arrop").attr("src","/img/arrowd.png");
        $('#userputrigger').attr("title", "Show options");
        $(".pass").toggleClass("act");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".ui").append('<div id="userpopup"><div class="options"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="icon"><img src="img/user.png" width="16" height="16" alt="My profile" /></td><td><a href="#">My profile</a></td></tr><tr><td class="icon"><img src="img/settings.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Settings" /></td><td><a href="#">Settings</a></td></tr><tr><td class="icon"><img src="img/calendar.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Watchlist" /></td><td><a href="#">Watchlist</a></td></tr><tr><td class="icon"><img src="img/prizeicon.png" width="16" height="16" alt="My contests" /></td><td><a href="#">My contests</a></td></tr><tr><td class="icon"><img src="img/music.png" width="16" height="16" alt="My beats" /></td><td><a href="#">My beats</a></td></tr><tr><td class="icon"><img src="img/coins.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Balance" /></td><td><a href="#">Balance</a></td></tr><tr class="last"><td class="icon"><img src="img/logout.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Logout" /></td><td><form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Logout" /><input type="hidden" name="logout" value="1" /></form></td></tr></table></div></div>');
        $(".pass").toggleClass("act");
        $(".arrop").attr("src","/img/arrowuact.png");
        $('#userputrigger').attr("title", "Hide options");
    }
    return false;
});

$('#userpopup').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    if ($('#userpopup').is(':visible'))
    {
        $(".arrop").attr("src","/img/arrowd.png");
        $("#userpopup").remove();
        $(".pass").toggleClass("act");
        $('#userputrigger').attr("title", "Show options");
    }
});
```

});

It actually works on the links but not on the submit button "logout". It just closes on Firefox.

Thanks :)

Comment: you should not use click event on document, instead you should put an id to the box end use $('#box_id').click()

Comment: How about some sample code?

Comment: Usually what people do is put up a background DIV that blocks the whole screen with the settings on top of that. Then if you click on the background DIV it is the same as clicking off of the window. So take a look at how lightbox-type things work.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you click on div with class "settings".
The following will prevent the document click propagation.

```
$('.settings').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();

   ...your stuff here...
});
```